# TextBlock binding to user property displays empty text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've bound many things without issue, but this one isn't working for some reason.  I have a base viewmodel that loads a property called User from the login window:

```
public void LoadUser()
   {
   if ((LoginState?)Application.Current.Properties["LoginState"] == LoginState.Success)
      {
      User = new UserModel((string)Application.Current.Properties["UserLName"], (string)Application.Current.Properties["UserFName"], (int)Application.Current.Properties["UserLevel"]);
      RaisePropertyChanged("User");
      }
   }
```

This part works fine according to the breakpoint values. This property User is in the base of the viewmodel that is attached as the DataContext of my MainWindow. I bind it on the view with this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, Source=User}"
           Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Black"/>
```

I know the text block works as I can bind other properties to it, but it won't display this property for some reason.  Can you see why?

Comment: is there a public property `Name` on the class `User`?

Comment: Yes, sir: in UserModel: public string Name { get; set; } -- when I breakpoint, the User property of the viewmodel is set just the way it should be

Comment: maybe `LoadUser` is run after the binding takes place...

Comment: It is run after the binding, but shouldn't the "RaisePropertyChanged("User") take care of that?

Comment: yeah - should do

Comment: to be honest really hard to say with what we can see from your question...

Comment: TextBlock's Default Binding MAY not be TwoWay. So Can you Set it to be TwoWay explicitly in xaml. Also, that RaisePropertyChanged is custom implementation right. Can you step into it during debug and see if the Event is Null?

Comment: A nice tool to debug such issues is Snoop (https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf). You might also want to enable writing WPF debug output to the Visual Studio output window in Tools/Options/Debugging/OutputWindow

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that tool may come in handy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextBlock's Default Binding MAY not be TwoWay. So Can you Set it to be TwoWay explicitly in xaml and check once.

Also, that RaisePropertyChanged is custom implementation right. Can you step into it during debug and see if the Event is Null?

Comment: It could have been the mode, I forgot to check that.  The RaisePropertyChanged is from MVVMLight.  I have the thing working correctly now, but I changed it to a (much) simpler version after realizing I didn't need to store the user in the Application Properties, I just store them in my Application's overall viewmodel as it will always be around.